# Python Regex replace value with match if contained by "{! and }"

Tags: python, regex, string

I would like to replace the contents of an attribute with the contents matching a regex within it ONLY if it is surrounded by "{! and }" including the quotes.

```
<lightning-button-menu iconname="utility:help" menualignment="right" onselect="{!c.handleMenuSelect}">
<lightning-menu-item label="Frequently Asked Questions" value="faq">
</lightning-menu-item>
```

onselect would look like the following:

```
onselect={handleMenuSelect}
```

If this sounds confusing please let me know so I can clarify

Comment: What have you searched for, and what did you find? What did you try, and how did it fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
s = '''
<lightning-button-menu iconname="utility:help" menualignment="right" onselect="{!c.handleMenuSelect}">
<lightning-menu-item label="Frequently Asked Questions" value="faq">
</lightning-menu-item>
'''


import re

for match in re.finditer('"{!(.*?)}"', s):
    s = s[:match.start()] + '{' + match.group(1).split('.', 1)[1] + '}' + s[match.end():]

print(s)
```

Result:

```
<lightning-button-menu iconname="utility:help" menualignment="right" onselect={handleMenuSelect}>
<lightning-menu-item label="Frequently Asked Questions" value="faq">
</lightning-menu-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

This must help you:

```
import re

string='''
<lightning-button-menu iconname="utility:help" menualignment="right" onselect="{!c.handleMenuSelect}">
<lightning-menu-item label="Frequently Asked Questions" value="faq">
</lightning-menu-item>
'''
for f in re.finditer(r'onselect="{![\S]+}"', string):
    string= string[:f.start()+len('onselect"{!')]+'handleMenuSelect'+string[f.end()-len('}"'):]

print(string)
```

where string is your text